# Guice linked binding versus @Provides method

Tags: java, guice

I have this problem.

Consider I have classes definitions like:

```
public interface ABCInterface 
{
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public class ABCImpl 
{       
  @Inject
  private XYZ xyz;
}
```

When the Guice Config is like this:

```
public class MasterConfig extends AbstractModule 
{    
  @Override
  protected void configure() 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bind(ABCInterface.class)
    .to(ABCImpl.class);
  }
}
```

And run it, then everything works fine and XYZ gets injected into it.

But when I use provider methods like this:

```
public class MasterConfig extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Provides
    public ABCInterface abc() {
        return new ABCImpl();
    }
}
```

Then, in this case, I get a null pointer exception when I try to use the injected XYZ, because that object remains null. I am suspecting, this is beacuse, I am returning a new object of ABCImpl and hence Guice is not able to build a dependency graph. Please correct me if I am wrong here?

Can anyone suggest, how to write the Provider method, so that everything gets injected properly like it does when I mention in the configure method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, when you write `new ABCImpl()`, Guice doesn't get a chance to inject its dependencies.  You can do this:

```
@Provides
ABCInterface abc(ABCImpl impl) {
    return impl;
}
```

but you might as well just write `bind(ABCInterface.class).to(ABCImpl.class);` in that case, unless your provider method has some extra logic.